# Serial reading syncing

Tags: c++, c, embedded, mbed, nucleo

I am using the hc-05 module to talk to my Nucleo board. however the information can arrive arranged in a way that is not how i want.

```
void BLE_thread(void){
    char read[0];
    uint16_t command = 0;
    while(1){
        //comm_mutex.lock();
        //comm_mutex.unlock();

        device.fsync();
        device.gets(read,2);
        command = read[0];
        device.gets(read,2);
        command += read[0]<<8;
        pc.printf("bytes = %X\r\n",command);
        read[0] = 0;
    }
}
```

The output is supposed to be ABCD however it can be unpredictable.

[image]

any suggestions on how to so the output the received bytes are always in the correct order?

Comment: Is the output really supposed to be ABDC, not ABCD?

Comment: The variable declaration `char read[0];` looks wrong. You will need positive number of elements.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this platform. Where is the documentation for `device.gets`?

Comment: Have you tried to activate the compiler warnings ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/

Comment: yes ABCD that was a typo, i have increased the array size and still has the same behaviour. the wrong outputs can be CDCD or CDAB but never ABAB if that gives any clues?

Comment: [cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) is definitely not the documentation for `device.gets` because the function on linked page take 1 argument while `device.gets` here takes 2 arguments.

Comment: This is the Serial APIs for what i am using their is no gets listed though. https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.15/apis/serial.html

Comment: Declare read variable as uint16_t.or type cast read[0] to uint16_t before left shifting by 8.

Comment: @jackgell: There is no gets() in that Serial class in that link. Though, I still guess, gets() also has a return value about the number of bytes it has put into the buffer. I guess, since you are polling without checking about, if data was actually received, your read array just contains the data from the previous gets() call.